# R ggplot bar graph not showing all colors

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am trying to plot a flipped bar graph to represent multiple ethnicities.
Here is the dataset:

```
race_dataset <- data.frame(
  workforce = c("leadership", "leadership", "leadership", "leadership", "leadership", "non_tech", "non_tech", "non_tech", "non_tech", "non_tech", "tech", "tech", "tech", "tech", "tech"),
  report_year = c(2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023),
  Asian = c(0.2890, 0.2960, 0.2940, 0.3120, 0.3230, 0.2515, 0.2610, 0.2610, 0.2640, 0.2705, 0.4505, 0.4745, 0.4810, 0.4940, 0.5065),
  Black = c(0.0260, 0.0300, 0.0300, 0.0470, 0.0520, 0.0660, 0.0725, 0.0845, 0.0990, 0.1055, 0.0215, 0.0245, 0.0300, 0.0360, 0.0405),
  Hispanic_Latinx = c(0.0330, 0.0390, 0.0390, 0.0410, 0.0430, 0.0900, 0.0925, 0.0945, 0.1005, 0.1075, 0.0460, 0.0480, 0.0535, 0.0580, 0.0620),
  Native_American = c(0.0070, 0.0050, 0.0060, 0.0070, 0.0080, 0.0135, 0.0130, 0.0125, 0.0125, 0.0130, 0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0060, 0.0070),
  White = c(0.6660, 0.6590, 0.6550, 0.6200, 0.6030, 0.6350, 0.6190, 0.6085, 0.5880, 0.5700, 0.5110, 0.4815, 0.4670, 0.4445, 0.4270)
)
```

But the color assignment does not work on the graph. [ratio showing all colors but on smaller scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUZ9W.png)

```
race_color_assignment <- c("Asian" = "#1f77b4", 
                           "Black" = "#ff7f0e", 
                           "Hispanic_Latinx" = "#2ca02c", 
                           "Native_American" = "#d62728", 
                           "White" = "#9467bd")

race_long_data <- melt(race_dataset, id.vars = c("workforce", "report_year"), 
                  variable.name = "race", value.name = "percentage")


race_long_data$race <- factor(race_long_data$race, levels = c("Asian", "Black", "Hispanic_Latinx", "Native_American", "White"))

generate_bargraph <- function(year, workforce) {
  race_data_subset <- race_long_data %>%
    filter(report_year == year, workforce == workforce)
  
  graph_title <- ifelse(year == 2019, "Workforce Representation by Race/Ethnicity", "")
  
  p <- ggplot(race_data_subset, aes(x = as.factor(report_year), y = percentage, fill = race)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack", width = 0.6) +
    geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(percentage, 2), "%")), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 3) +
    coord_flip(ylim = c(0, 120)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = race_color_assignment, labels = paste0(race_data_subset$race, " ", race_data_subset$percentage, "%")) +
    labs(x = " ", y = "Percentage", fill = "Race/Ethnicity", title = graph_title) +
    theme_excel_new() +
    theme(
      plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 16),
      axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 14),
      axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 14),
      axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12),
      axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12),
      panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
      strip.text = element_text(face = "bold", size = 14),
      legend.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 14),
      legend.text = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12)
    )
# Generate graphs for all combinations
for(year in 2019:2023){
  for(workforce in unique(race_long_data$workforce)){
    generate_bargraph(year, workforce)
  }
}
```

I want the x-axis for percentage so it is 1-120 because it is multiracial, and the data does not add up to one. I tried changing the decimal to percentage "* 100" in the initial dataset preparation, it will show the color but the bar are on a smaller scale. [percentage showing only one color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM0G0.png)

Comment: Please make your problem _minimal_ and _reproducible_. We don't have your data, and therefore cannot know what format the data is in after all your data wrangling. Please provide a small data sample and the minimal code needed to reproduce your issue rather than posting a large script. Even if someone here had the time and patience to read through all your code, they still wouldn't know what's going on because they don't have the input data. You can [edit] your question at any time to change it into one that folks here might have a chance of helping you with. Thanks.

Comment: Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064), use a reproducible format like `dput()` to share sample data in your question.

Comment: “120% of the workforce” doesn’t really make much sense. I think you need to rethink your summary measure.

Comment: Hi Limey, people claim to be multiracial, like mix of asian and white, so the total of ethnicity does not add up to 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you want your final figure to look like, but you may likely benefit from pivoting longer then creating the figure:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

race_long <- race_dataset %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(Asian:White, names_to = "race", values_to = "value")

# workforce  report_year race            value
# <chr>            <dbl> <chr>           <dbl>
# 1 leadership        2019 Asian           0.289
# 2 leadership        2019 Black           0.026
# 3 leadership        2019 Hispanic_Latinx 0.033
# 4 leadership        2019 Native_American 0.007
# 5 leadership        2019 White           0.666
# 6 leadership        2020 Asian           0.296
# ....

# Color assignment from OP
race_color_assignment <- c("Asian" = "#1f77b4", 
                           "Black" = "#ff7f0e", 
                           "Hispanic_Latinx" = "#2ca02c", 
                           "Native_American" = "#d62728", 
                           "White" = "#9467bd")
```

The you can plot your data according to both `report_year` and `workforce` using facets, and also control the axis (technically the y axis, not x - it is just pivoted to "look" like the x axis, but still need to use `scale_y_continuous()`). The colors can be assigned quickly with `scale_fill_manual()`:

```
ggplot(race_long, aes(fill = race, y = value, x = report_year)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() + 
  xlab("Year") + ylab("Cumulative Percent") +
  facet_wrap(~workforce) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = race_color_assignment) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,1.1,0.1), 
                     labels = paste0(seq(0,110,10), "%"))
```

[image]

Or if you want a 3x5 grid as indicated in the comments, try `facet_grid`:

```
ggplot(race_long, aes(fill = race, y = value, x = 1)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  xlab("Year") + ylab("Cumulative Percent") +
  facet_grid(rows = vars(report_year), 
             cols = vars(workforce),
             switch = "y") +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = race_color_assignment) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,1.1,0.1), 
                     labels = paste0(seq(0,110,10), "%")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0, labels = "")
```

[image]

or if you switch the rows/columns in `facet_grid`:
[image]

If you want to make 15 separate plots, you can wrap it in a function and create the plots like this:

```
myplot <- function(year, workforce){
  ggplot(race_long[race_long$report_year %in% year &
                   race_long$workforce %in% workforce,], aes(fill = race, y = value, x = report_year)) + 
    geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
    coord_flip() +
    xlab("Year") + ylab("Cumulative Percent") +
    theme_classic() +
    scale_fill_manual(values = race_color_assignment) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1.1, 0.1),
                       labels = paste0(seq(0, 110, 10), "%"))
}

myplot("2019", "leadership")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi jpsmith, I was able to generate a similar graph like yours. I am trying to generate 3 * 5 plots for each race/workforce combination instead.

Comment: @Scarlett see edit - is this what you are looking for?

Comment: no, I want 15 separate plots

Comment: @Scarlett see edit - if you want 15 separate plots, you can then loop through the user defined function `myplot`

Comment: it worked perfectly! thank you jpsmith